Can we cancel out light in the same way we do sound using interference?
I understand sound waves interfere and, if organised strategically, can cancel each other out to produce what is basically silence. My question is: since waves of light can produce their own interference patterns (for example the double slit experiment), is it possible to create darkness by strategically organising sources of light? Intuitively I think this isn't possible, furthermore I don't have the strongest understanding of the wave particle duality of light and its limitations. A few sources told me electromagnetic waves do not interact in the same way that mechanical waves do. However, given that in situations, such as the double slit experiment, light can possess the ability to cancel itself out, is it possible to create patches of darkness with no light source?

I fear you might need to run this question through a spell checker...

Interference is the absence of self-interaction in linear fields. Light is a linear field phenomenon and can therefor show interference.

https://www.sfu.ca/phys/346/121/resources/physics_of_microwave_ovens.pdf Cold spots in microwaves

Surely you've seen laser speckle? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_(interference)

Yes. and this is done in labs and products already.
The shortest quickest answer is to refer you to youngs double slit experiment as yhou've mentioned, passing light through two slits will allow you to see destructive and constructive interference peaks.
Lasers can be constructed today in a way so that instead of forming a pulse of laser light (of course in a pulsed laser scenario, not continuous wave), the laser will form a dark pulse, a temporally localized region where the phases of the modes present cancel each other out and the existence of 'nothing' locally occurs.
One practical example is for example smartphones face scanner (to unlock your phone). Typically they consist of VCSEL-arrays in which the individual VCSELs (vertical cavity surface mitting laser) are driven in and out of phase with each other to scan the beam across your phase. This article mainly talks about radio waves, but the principle is the same.
Another example perhaps closer to your exact question is the existence of the cosmic microwave backround radioation cold spot, a cold spot in the CMWBR where there is a lower amount of light than expected.
To summarize, the scenario you describe where let's say a whole room or something is canceled out is technically difficult to do, however theoretically nothing prohibits it. Keep in mind though that just as with sound waves, the electromagnetic waves would need to be coherent enough for this to be possible. "Noisy" light can not be interefered on a large scale.

What does the CMWBR have to do with light interference? Are you claiming light waves are interfering there to produce a different spectrum?! That sounds decidedly weird.

no, vcsels are not driven out of phase to scan your face

Mediums like air and water are pretty efficient and as far as we know the EM field is perfectly efficient. SO energy is never destroyed in a medium, i.e. water waves can interact and superimpose but the waves pass thru each other ... the waves only get absorbed when they crash on the beach or on the rocks.
For light we can never observe the medium directly (as we can for air or water), light is best understood as a localized (small) wave in the EM field ... the photon always has wave properties ... it is massless ... and can also be considered as a quanta.  The particle nature relates to the quanta effect and is very historical but also the particle nature is also supported by the STANDARD MODEL (SM).  The SM is a not very helpful ... it says all things are either a field OR an excitation of a field (particle).
Photons never cancel each other either, once they are emitted eventually they must be absorbed. Light travels in a wave resonant manner, in the slit experiment no photons travel to the dark areas.

The only property that matters for interference is linearity. Not sure why you are dragging the standard model in here. In the standard model light is a very special kind of quantum field for which linearity is guaranteed by design (of the theory). If light wasn't a linear phenomenon, then the standard model would not look the way it looks.

This isn't a physics question, it's an engineering question.
In theory, the answer is "yes, for a small region", but there are problems.
Sound is what, 16 Hz -10 KHz? Active cancelation headphones can measure that an immediately generate an opposite phase signal, near your eardrum, because the fastest time scale is 0.1 ms--no problem for modern electronics. All you have to do is move a diaphragm.
The light analogy has several problems:
You have to move charges and currents...how?
You have to contend with two polarization states.
You need to operate at 400-700 THz, which is too fast for electronics.
At work, I'm currently > 100 GHz, and can't believe we have hardware for that.

Hi, thanks for responding! Do you know what specific area of engineering this is I would love to look further into it

@liv.ysf Calling it an engineering problem is a polite was of saying it's not feasible rn. You need phase information. The highest digitally frequency I've heard about is Sandia's Ka SAR. At optical ppl use analog systems with laser and do heterodyne detection, but I really don't know that much about it.
